# Android - Read Touch Screen in Loop/Handler?

Tags: java, android, android-handler

Can I read touch screen inputs inside my handler ?

```
            final Handler handler=new Handler();
            final int[] A = new int[1];
            X[0] =0;
            handler.post(new Runnable() {


                @Override
                public void run() {

                If Touch B = True etc Else B = False
                int X[0] = getX();

                    TXT.setText(String.format("%d", X[0], B));
                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);
                    image.setX(300+ A[0]);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 10);
```

It look like your post is mostly code; please add some more detail

Comment: What does "read touch screen inputs" mean? You get touch events delivered to you via callbacks, [such as `onTouchEvent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)).

Comment: So I can GetX  GetY coordinates inside the loop is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You receive touch events via callback methods, [such as `onTouchEvent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)).

Comment: @MharlesCanson: That seems rather unlikely. But, you are certainly welcome to answer your own question and provide a demonstration of what you have done, to benefit others.

Answer (score 0):

Sure

```
 final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.Laydown);
            handler.post(new Runnable() {


                @Override
                public void run() {


                    layot.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                        @Override
                      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            TXT.setText("Touch coordinates : " + String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
                            return true;
                        }
                    });


                    handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
```